# Calculating probabilities symbolically

Tags: symbolic, probability-or-statistics

Is there a way to solve for statistical quantities analytically/symbolically in *Mathematica*?

**example 1:**
Lets say that I want to do a calculation that requires Bayes theorem.

I know p(a), p(b) and p(a | b). I want to calculate p(b | a).

Now, for this simple example, I know the solution, so I could write the relationship myself, but what about more complicated examples? Surely *Mathematica* is able to solve probability problems like it can solve algebraic ones? I want to stay away from simulation. I want *Mathematica* to do the five pages of math that I normally do on paper. Can *Mathematica* do this for me?

I'd like to type something like

```
Solve[p(a) == a1 && p(b) == a2 && p(a|b) == a3, p(b|a)]
```

and get

> ```
> p(b|a) -> (a3*a2)/a1
> ```

**example 2:**
I want to use the law of total probability:

I know `p(a|b)`, `p(a|!b)`, and `p(b)` and I want to calculate `p(a)`.

I'd like to type something like

```
Solve[p(a|b) == a1 && p(a|!b) == a2 && p(b) == a3, p(a)]
```

and get

> ```
> p(a) -> a1*a3 + a2*(1-a3)
> ```

Comment: What do you mean with p(a|!b) ? I've never seen this notation.

Comment: @eldo, I mean p(a| not b)

Comment: Like two dices NOT showing the same number - could you give an example ?

Comment: The only example I ever encountered of a symbolic evaluation of Bayes equation is by Gregory Klopper in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887519/how-do-you-work-out-conditional-probabilities-in-mathematica-is-it-possible).

Comment: thanks @RomkeBontekoe, I've seen that too. Its a great example, but its not as general as it could be. I'm going to assume that Mathematica cannot do such a calculation out of the box.

Comment: Mathematica 10 just came out, I wonder if there is any chance its now possible

Comment: Given that events A and B are independent with P(A)=0.1P(A)=0.1 and P(B|A)=0.41P(B∣A)=0.41, determine the value of P(B)P(B), rounding to the nearest thousandth, if necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is code for a function `bSolve` which is to be used essentially like `Solve`.  Given some equations as its first argument and some variables (or in fact more complicated expressions) as its second argument, it finds the values of the variables, eliminating all occurrences of `p[...]`.  The probability of `a` is denoted by `p[a]` and the conditional probability of `a` given `b` is denoted `p[a, b]`.  It wouldn't be hard to have support for `\[Conditioned]` if you want.

This code works by writing all probabilities in terms of the 2^n joint probabilities `p[a&&b&&...]`, `p[!a&&b&&...]`, `p[a&&!b&&...]` etc. (where n is the number of different events).  Then we write all relevant equations, eliminate the `p[...]` and are left with the values of `g[...]` requested by the user.

```
p::usage = 
  "In bSolve, p[a] denotes the probability of a, and p[a, b] denotes \
the conditional probability of a given b." ;
bSolve::usage = 
  "bSolve[eqs, vars] tries to solve a system of equations eqs on \
probabilities p[a] or conditional probabilities p[a, b] \
(conventionally denoted p(a|b)) for the variables vars.";
Begin["bSolve`"];
Unprotect[bSolve, p];
Clear[bSolve, p];
bSolve[eqs : Except[_List], goal_] := bSolve[{eqs}, goal];
bSolve[eqs_, goal : Except[_List]] := bSolve[eqs, {goal}];
bSolve[eqs_List, goal_List] := (
   goalvars = g /@ Range[Length[goal]];
   alleqs = Join[eqs, Thread[goalvars == goal]];
   argsofp = Cases[alleqs, p[a___] :> a, Infinity];
   vars = 
    List @@ Union@(d @@ argsofp //.
          d[a___, (Not | And | Or | Xor)[b___], c___] :> d[a, b, c]);
   qtab = Table[q[i - 1], {i, 2^Length[vars]}];
   ptab = 
    p /@ Flatten@Outer[And, Sequence @@ Table[{a, Not[a]}, {a, vars}]];
   sols = 
    Solve[Eliminate[
      Join[{Total[qtab] == 1}, 
       alleqs /. {p[x_, y_] :> p[x && y]/p[y]} /. 
        p[x_] :> (qtab.Boole@BooleanTable[x, vars])], qtab], goalvars];
   Thread[goal -> goalvars] /. sols
   );
SyntaxInformation[p] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _.}};
SyntaxInformation[bSolve] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _}};
Protect[bSolve, p];
End[];
```

Let's test:

```
bSolve[{p[a] == a1, p[b] == a2, p[a, b] == a3}, {p[b, a], p[! b], 
  p[a && b], p[Xor[a, b]]}]

(*=> {{p[b, a] -> (a2 a3)/a1, p[! b] -> 1 - a2, p[a && b] -> a2 a3, 
  p[a \[Xor] b] -> a1 + a2 - 2 a2 a3}}*)

bSolve[p[a, b] == a1 && p[a, ! b] == a2 && p[b] == a3, p[a]]

(*=> {{p[a] -> a2 + a1 a3 - a2 a3}}*)
```

and an example from an [2011 Stackoverflow question on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887519/how-do-you-work-out-conditional-probabilities-in-mathematica-is-it-possible):

```
bSolve[p[Cancer] == 0.01 && p[Test, Cancer] == 0.9 && 
  p[Test, ! Cancer] == 0.2, p[Cancer, Test]]

(*=> {{p[Cancer, Test] -> 0.0434783}}*)
```

Comment: You are awesome

Comment: How could this be extended to include multiple arguments in the probability? For example, in my case I have values like P(A, B | C) and P(D | E, F) (the commas are the intersection / "and" operator)

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own discrete probability distributions and then use built-in functions. The following uses this approach if the following are known: p(a),p(b},p(a|b). It can be adapted for other scenario. I present it as motivation.

```
pr[pa_, pb_, pagb_] := Module[{s},
  s = First@
    Solve[{p00 + p10 + p01 + p11 == 1, p11 == pagb pb, 
      p10 + p11 == pa, p01 + p11 == pb}, {p00, p01, p10, p11}];
  ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{
     {p00 /. s, x == 0 && y == 0},
     {p01 /. s, x == 0 && y == 1},
     {p10 /. s, x == 1 && y == 0},
     {p11 /. s, x == 1 && y == 1}}],
   {x, 0, 1, 1}, {y, 0, 1, 1}]
  ]
full[u_, v_, w_] := Module[{pd, t, r, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5},
  pd = pr[u, v, w];
  t = Tuples[{0, 1}, 2];
  r = Thread[t -> {"Not a,Not b", "Not a, b", "a,Not b", "a,b"}];
  w1 = {# /. r, 
      Probability[{x, y} == #, {x, y} \[Distributed] pd]} & /@ t;
  w2 = {StringForm["`1` given `2`", 
       Sequence @@ (StringSplit[{#1, #2} /. r, ","])], 
      Probability[
       x == #1 \[Conditioned] y == #2, {x, y} \[Distributed] pd]} & @@@
     t;
  w3 = {StringForm["`2` given `1`", 
       Sequence @@ (StringSplit[{#1, #2} /. r, ","])], 
      Probability[
       y == #2 \[Conditioned] x == #1, {x, y} \[Distributed] pd]} & @@@
     t;
  w4 = {"a", Probability[x == 1, {x, y} \[Distributed] pd]};
  w5 = {"b", Probability[y == 1, {x, y} \[Distributed] pd]};
  Row[{Framed[
     TableForm[w1~Join~w2~Join~w3~Join~{w4}~Join~{w5}, 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {"Event", "Probability"}}]],
    DiscretePlot3D[PDF[pd, {x, y}], {x, {0, 1}}, {y, {0, 1}}, 
     ExtentSize -> Full, Ticks -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "Probability"}, ImageSize -> 300]}, 
   Frame -> True]]
```

Examples:

1. Case with dependency:

   ```
   full[0.5, 0.3, 0.25]
   ```

   [image]
2. Independent:

   ```
   full[0.6, 0.3, 0.6]
   ```

[image]