# Bayesian Inference

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am using `bSolve` which is worked out at this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51994/calculating-probabilities-symbolically)

Using a simple, single condition, example I get the same result with either bSolve or a decision tree

Then, using this input with two conditions

```
bSolve[p[SmBldg] == 0.12 && p[Def, SmBldg] == 2/3 && 
p[Def, ! SmBldg] == 1 - 40/(180 + 40), p[Def, SmBldg]][[1]]
[[1]]
```

The answer I get is
(*  `p[Def, SmBldg] -> 0.666667`  *)

BUT, this is an intermediate result. See below. Double checking with a decision tree I get the answer you see below. The context is Tenants (T) in either a small (SmBldg) or large (LgBldg) apartment building and whether they perform their lease (Perf) or default (Def).
[image: Decision Tree]